# Deploying resources with CloudFormation based on existing infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

**The Situation**

We need to generate a CloudFormation template to be deployed by a 3rd party in their AWS account, on top of their existing infrastructure.

The CFT will attach a Kinesis Firehose delivery stream to an existing source, owned by the 3rd party. **BUT** there could be two different scenarios in this deployment, based on the what the 3rd party has already deployed.

We want to automate the deployment as much as possible.

**The choice**

1. We can ask the 3rd party to choose a suitable CFT to match the infrastructure their already have.

*OR*

2. We can create a single CFT that will determine the state of the existing 3rd party infrastructure and conditionally deploy new resources

**The question**

How can, if at all, the 2nd option be achieved?